# Input and Output in the Same Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm pretty new using Microsoft Access and I'm wondering is it possible to perform a query that uses input in a form and then show the results within the same form. (FYI, my query only outputs one result) For example:

**Input**

Project ID: BC1234

Project Type: BC

Project Name: Hello

Resource Name: John

Project Status: Null

Project Start Date: Null

Project End Date: Null

**Output**

Project ID: BC1234

Project Type: BC

Project Name: Hello World

Resource Name: John Smith

Project Status: Active

Project Start Date: 7/11/17

Project End Date: 7/20/17

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subform.

First create a form that contains the list of data you want to see.  In your case it would be the projects table or a query based on the list of projects you want to see.  Such as all Active.

Second, modify your existing input form to include a subform control and set the subform Source Object property to the name of the form you just created above.  If this was data related to your project you would need to make sure the Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields are filled in.  Access will try and do this for you if it finds the same name for the fields.  If they are not the same, you can fill it in yourself.  However, in your case, you want to see a list of all the projects so you would leave these two properties blank.  If you don't leave them blank, it will filter the subform to the selected record.

After you save a record you can add this to the code to refresh the data in the subform.

Me.nameofthesubform.Requery

This can be done in a command button or on one of the form events.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a subform. The inputs can be unbound controls - just add textboxes to the form, not tied to a data source. The form's data source can be your query. User fills in the textboxes, clicks a button, and you refresh the form to see results, if any.